# Is there a testnet version of data.ripple.com -- the Ripple Data API v2?

Tags: ripple

I am looking for a testnet version of data.ripple.com -- the Ripple Data API v2. Does anyone know if there is such a thing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

At https://medium.com/interledger-blog/sending-out-of-the-interledger-network-9f42c1217c72 there was a link to https://testnet.data.api.ripple.com/v2/ which seems to be what I was looking for.